# RecyclerView position wrong when I scroll it too fast

Tags: android

It's a complicated RecyclerView Holder,the question is when I scroll it fast to top,the position will be deranged.log just like this:
[it's log about position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvhUN.png)

my adapter is like this:

```
class StoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.HEADER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_header_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TEXT:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_text_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TextViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.IMAGE:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_image_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_GRANDPA:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_grandpa_letter_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new GrandpaLetterHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_USER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_user_letter_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new UserLetterHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_TITLE:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comment_title_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentTitleHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_PLACE_HOLDER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_place_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new PlaceHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENT_HEADER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_rcommend_comment_header_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ReCommentHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comments_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentsHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_HEADER:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comment_header_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentHeaderHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENTS:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_comments_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CommentsHolder(itemView);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TIP:
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.story_tip_holder, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TipHolder(itemView);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.HEADER:
                HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
                headerViewHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));

                boolean hideSubmission =
                        TYPE_NAME_MAIL_FROM_GRANDPA.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title.subtitle) ||
                                TYPE_NAME_BULLETIN.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title.subtitle) ||
                                TYPE_ID_BULLETIN.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title._id) ||
                                TYPE_ID_MAIL_FROM_GRANDPA.equals(storyDetail.formats.get(position).title._id);

                setSubmissionButtonState(!hideSubmission);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TEXT:
                TextViewHolder textViewHolder = (TextViewHolder) holder;
                textViewHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.IMAGE:
                ImageViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
                imageViewHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_GRANDPA:
                GrandpaLetterHolder grandpaLetterHolder = (GrandpaLetterHolder) holder;
                grandpaLetterHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.FROM_USER:
                UserLetterHolder userLetterHolder = (UserLetterHolder) holder;
                userLetterHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_TITLE:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_PLACE_HOLDER:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENT_HEADER:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS:
                **Log.e("position", position + "");**
                CommentsHolder commentsHolder = (CommentsHolder) holder;
                commentsHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position), R.mipmap.story_comment_icon_brown,
                        position + 1 < getItemCount() && storyDetail.formats.get(position + 1).type != StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENT_HEADER:
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.COMMENTS:
                CommentsHolder commentsHolder1 = (CommentsHolder) holder;
                commentsHolder1.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position), R.mipmap.story_comment_mine_icon_black, false);
                break;
            case StoryDetail.FormatType.TIP:
                TipHolder tipHolder = (TipHolder) holder;
                tipHolder.setData(storyDetail.formats.get(position));
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (storyDetail == null || storyDetail.formats == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return storyDetail.formats.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        super.getItemViewType(position);
        return storyDetail.formats.get(position).type;
    }
```

so,as you see, there are lots of type.
when I scroll slowly,it works fine.
by the way,it's only happened scroll to top.
please help me , thanks a lot! :)

Comment: why do you think the `position` is wrong?

Comment: because When I log the position and scroll to top,it's not like 15,14,13,12...but is 15,14,20,19,21.....

Comment: but are your views bound ok or not?

Comment: it's not OK...as this sample,after position 5,it is a list.but because of position isn't correct , when I want scroll to top,the list item will move in cycles....

Comment: Move the Log to the beginning of the onBindViewHolder(). Right now you're only logging the position only if the viewType is StoryDetail.FormatType.RECOMMEND_COMMENTS and check the position

Comment: well,I'v try it again.wherever I log the position , it will be same value and wrong